# RuntimeError: mean(): input dtype should be either floating point or complex dtypes. Got Long instead

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I wrote below code using pytorch and ran into a runtime error:

```
tns = torch.tensor([1,0,1])
tns.mean()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-666-194e5ab56931> in <module>
----> 1 tns.mean()

RuntimeError: mean(): input dtype should be either floating point or complex dtypes. Got Long instead.
```

However, if I change the tensor to float, the error goes away:

```
tns = torch.tensor([1.,0,1])
tns.mean()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
tensor(0.6667)
```

My question is why the error happens. The data type of the first tenor is int64 instead of Long, why does PyTorch take it as Long?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `torch.int64` and `torch.long` both refer to the same data type, of 64-bit signed integers. See [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_attributes.html) for an overview of all data types.

Answer (score 6):

You should change 'torch.tensor([1,0,1])' to 'torch.Tensor([1,0,1]).